# How can I get my css to render correctly in django?

Tags: css, django

So I'm a newbie and I'm having trouble getting my css to render in Django. I am attempting to create a red notification like in Facebook for my unread messages. But my css isn't rendering. What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code

**settings.py/Static_Dir**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]
```

**notification.css**

```
.btn {
width:100px;
position:relative;
line-height:50px;
}

.notification {
    position:absolute;
    right:-7px;
    top:-7px;
    background-color:red;
    line-height:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

**base.html/notification section**

```
<link href="{% static 'notification.css' %}">
            <button class="btn">message counter
                <div class="notification">{% unread_messages request.user %}</div>
            </button>
```

**EDIT, adding directory path**

```
.
├── 11_env
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── activate.csh
│   │   ├── activate.fish
│   │   ├── django-admin
│   │   ├── django-admin.py
│   │   ├── easy_install
│   │   ├── easy_install-3.7
│   │   ├── pip
│   │   ├── pip3
│   │   ├── pip3.7
│   │   ├── python -> python3
│   │   ├── python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
│   │   └── sqlformat
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.7
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── dating_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── chat.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── profile_photo
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20200410_2231.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20200411_2011.py
│   │   ├── 0004_auto_20200413_1930.py
│   │   ├── 0005_auto_20200413_1946.py
│   │   ├── 0006_auto_20200413_2222.py
│   │   ├── 0007_auto_20200422_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0008_auto_20200425_0039.py
│   │   ├── 0009_auto_20200426_1957.py
│   │   ├── 0010_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0011_auto_20200426_2005.py
│   │   ├── 0012_auto_20200426_2007.py
│   │   ├── 0013_auto_20200427_1846.py
│   │   ├── 0014_auto_20200503_1947.py
│   │   ├── 0015_auto_20200503_2011.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── notification.css
│   ├── tag.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── dating_app
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── unread_messages_counter.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── dating_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

Comment: What is your directory hierarchy? Can you update that to the question

Comment: You also need to do: `python manage.py collectstatic` so your css (and other static files) are collected and recognized by Django.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Hey, I just added it. Take a look and let me know what's wrong

Comment: Can you try rendering this `{{ static }}`and `{{ STATIC_URL  ]}` and state the output ?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 When I render static, I get a couple not found errors, such as Not Found: /dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Not Found: /assets/js/vendor/popper.min.j

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 same thing happens when I run static_url

Comment: Where is your `base.html` in your tree structure? Seems like it's not set properly.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 It's in my template folder and within 'dating_app'

Comment: It's weird, I really can't tell where this could be going wrong. Your easiest option is to use the full path to the CSS manually if that would do that job. You may also try to add a css folder and place that in the static root dir. So you can use it like `static 'css/notification.css` and see if this solves it?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 It's weird, because it's taking me to the file. The link I'm creating is taking me to the file and showing me my css file content. but it's not creating the little red icon next to inbox, it's just inbox and the number of unread messages all in one pretty much. How can I use full path?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to add `rel="stylesheet"` in your link tag. Like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'notification.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also, make sure your css file is in root of the `/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static` folder.

Comment: Hmmm, adding 'stylesheet' didn't work. I just posted my project directory. Let me know what I'm doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

variable name for static should be `STATICFILES_DIR` not `STATICFILES_DIRS`. I hope this little typo solve your problem!

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` is correct:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

Answer (score 0):

Given all possible solutions in the comments didn't work, you may try this as your final attempt.

Add

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

to load staticfiles first, and then you can use the static tag. This is mostly used for **Django** < 2.0 though

Comment: If this doesn't work, then consider asking another question, in a concise clear manner to attract views and answers. Until then just use `Internal CSS` if that helps.

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring it out. I'll post the answer in a second, but I'm running into a separate issue with my if statement because I only want the notifier to trigger if there are greater than 0 messages. If you can take a look at that question, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

so this is what ended up working for me.

I first moved the link to the header area
**base.html/header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
```

I then included everything inside of the hyperlink like so and included the link to my inbox

**base.html/message_notifier**

```
                    <li>
                        <a ref = 'stylesheet'   href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css"     class="notification"> 
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                            <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```